# Calculate Difference with datetime.now().time()

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to write some code that will allow me to calculate the difference in time between two variables set to two datetime.now().time() results. I eventually want to make it so that if the difference is above a certain amount of minutes, that I can take some action - but unfortunately can't progress to that until I can get the difference.

Currently, I have the below, but I get an error of (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'). I have tried casting to ints, but still get the error.

```py
def check_recent_activity():
    current_time = datetime.now().time()
    time.sleep(5) # temporary, to ensure times are different enough. In actual functionality, one datetime will be a value in a dict
    current_time_2 = datetime.now().time()
    difference = current_time - current_time_2
    print("The difference between time 1 and 2 is: " + difference)
```

Comment: Consider using `datetime.now()` instead of `datetime.now().time()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't subtract two instances of `datetime.time` but you can subtract two instances of `datetime.datetime`.
That means using `datetime.now()` instead of `datetime.now().time()`.

```
def check_recent_activity():
    current_time = datetime.now()
    time.sleep(5) # temporary, to ensure times are different enough. In actual functionality, one datetime will be a value in a dict
    current_time_2 = datetime.now()
    difference = current_time_2 - current_time
    print("The difference between time 1 and 2 is:", difference)
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply cannot subtract `time` objects they will have to be `datetime` objects. You can either get your `datetime` pbject with the `datetime.datetime.now()` function or combine those times to a date using the `combine()` function. Then when subtracting two `datetime` objects you will get a `timedelta` object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) objects to do what you want:

```
import time

def check_recent_activity():
    current_time = time.time()
    time.sleep(5) # temporary, to ensure times are different enough. In actual functionality, one datetime will be a value in a dict
    current_time_2 = time.time()
    difference = current_time_2 - current_time
    print("The difference between time 1 and 2 is: " + str(difference))
             
check_recent_activity()
```